# Computing proportions of data frame in R and Converting Data Frame to Table

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to use `prop.table()` function to find proportion in data frame. To use `prop.table()` function, the object has to be table. So, here's what I did:

```
kids<-c("Jack","Jill")
ages<-c(25,66)
test<-c(0.1,0.3)
d<-data.frame(kids, ages,test, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I did a sanity check just to ensure that my data frame is okay:

```
sapply(d,class)
```

which gave me

```
#     kids        ages        test 
# "character"   "numeric"   "numeric" 
class(d)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

Now to convert *d* to table, I googled and found that one way is to convert dataframe to matrix and then to table.

So, here's what I did:

```
dtable<-(as.table(as.matrix(d)))
sapply(dtable,mode)
       Jack        Jill          25          66         0.1         0.3 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

**Question #1: I am not quite sure why the function converted all numerics to character?**
I am asking this because here's what I found when I googled:

```
melvin <- data.frame(x=c(3,1,3,2),y=c(3,3,4,5))
clyde   <- as.table(as.matrix(melvin))
prop.table(clyde,1)
```

This code works well. Here's the confirmation:

```
sapply(clyde,mode)
[1] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
prop.table(clyde,1)
          x         y
A 0.5000000 0.5000000
B 0.2500000 0.7500000
C 0.4285714 0.5714286
D 0.2857143 0.7142857
```

I am a little confused why this is happening. Why is my code not working?

**Question 2: If there is any shortcut to do this. I'd appreciate your help.**

I am a beginner so, I am sorry if this sounds too basic. However, I do believe that I have spent about 7 hours on researching this.

Comment: `matrix` is homogenous data structure, which means it only stores data of one type. Your original data frame has both character and numeric type and when you convert it to a matrix it coerce the numeric type to character type by default so that it doesn't lose information.

Comment: Oh I see. You are correct. Thanks Psidom. So, what's the solution? I will be having mixed data type in my file. Any thoughts?

Comment: The example you provided is not very informative, there are only two entities there. I don't see how `prop.table` can fit here. `prop.table` has something to do with conditional probability.

Comment: ALso here's a reference http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html

Answer (score 0):

Response to question 1
Read `?as.matrix`

You will note, it says:

> The default method for as.matrix calls as.vector(x), and hence e.g.`
>   coerces factors to character vectors.

Since you made a data.frame with mixed variables, and also used the option
`stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, you have data.frame with characters.

Do this instead

```
kids<-c("Jack","Jill")
ages<-c(25,66)
test<-c(0.1,0.3)
d<-data.frame(kids, ages,test, stringsAsFactors = T)
```

and then

```
as.table(as.matrix(d))
#exclude the first   character/factor column
d_ForProp.table <- as.table(as.matrix(d[,-1]))
d.prop.table <-prop.table(d_ForProp.table)
rownames(d.prop.table) <-d$kids #assign rownames to match kids
```

Finally, why do you want prop.table? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I did it, but it still doesn't work: dtable<-as.table(as.matrix(d))
> dtable
  kids ages test
A Jack 25   0.1 
B Jill 66   0.3 
> prop.table(dtable,1)
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
> sapply(dtable,class)
       Jack        Jill          25          66         0.1         0.3 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character"

Comment: Whoops, I had hit enter too soon and forgot to include the last few lines.Look at edit now

Comment: Hello infominer, thanks for your help. I was just trying to calculate relative frequencies, given the count. The data that I am working with has mixed data types. Is there any other method than prop.table() to accomplish this? Thanks in advance for your help.